# VB- Using INNER JOIN and display data

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, join, datagrid

What I need to do is:

- Select a `.mdb` file
- Display on a `DataGrid` 2 fields from `Table1` and 1 field from `table2`
- Save the table as a new database

I'm stuck on point 2, I can't join the two tables, I've been using `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

My `.mdb` DB has 2 tables, each with `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Field3`.
I want to display `Table1.Field1`, `Table1.Field2`, `Table2.Field3`.

My code (on a `button_click` event) is:

```
 Dim openFile As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFile.FileName = ""
    openFile.Filter = "Microsoft Access Application (*.mdb)|*.mdb"

    Dim res As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult = openFile.ShowDialog()
    If res = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim CONNECT_STRING As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + openFile.FileName
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(CONNECT_STRING)
    cnn.Open()

    'PROBLEM HERE
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT Tabla1.Campo1, Tabla1.Campo2, Tabla2.Campo3"
    Sql += " FROM Tabla1 LEFT JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.Campo3 = Tabla2.Campo3"


    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, cnn)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "joined")
    dGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("joined")
    cnn.Close()
```

Using this code, in only shows Fields 1 and 2 from table 1.

But if I change this:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT Tabla1.Campo1, Tabla1.Campo2, Tabla2.Campo3"
Sql += " FROM Tabla1 LEFT JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.Campo3 = Tabla2.Campo3"
```

To this:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT Tabla1.Campo1, Tabla1.Campo2,Tabla2.Campo3"
Sql += " FROM Tabla1 LEFT JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.ID = Tabla2.ID"
```

It will work!

But why?

How I'm supposed to re-arrange my fields on my new table if my real MDB has many more tables and fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
My problem was I didn't know how exactly INNER JOIN was supposed to work.
I'll explain in case anyone has the same problem i had.
to use INNER JOIN the tables you want to join must have 1 field in common, usually this is the ID, but in my case, my database didn't have one.

So, in solve my problem, I needed to create an ID Field with this code:

```
 Dim oQuery As String = "ALTER TABLE FloatTable ADD COLUMN ID Identity(1,1)"
    Dim oComm = New OleDbCommand(oQuery, cnn)
        oComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

After that, I was able to use INNER JOIN without any problem:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT FloatTable.DateAndTime, FloatTable.Millitm, FloatTable.TagIndex, FloatTable.Val, StringTable.TagIndex"
    Sql += " FROM FloatTable INNER JOIN StringTable ON FloatTable.ID = StringTable.ID"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `da.SelectCommand = cmd` instead of `da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)`
and see if that works. That's really the only thing that I can think of. Your code looks good.